# Retrieve post from flask using a string

Tags: python, html, sql, sqlite, flask

How can I retrieve the data from POST in Flask using a for loop in python. I want to dynamically build pages and this would be very useful.

```
schema=['username', 'phone', 'postal_code', 'address', 'email']
for i in schema:
if request.form.get(i):
    db.execute("UPDATE manpower SET :field=:input WHERE username=:username", field=i, input=request.form.get(i), username=request.form.get("user"))
else:
    print(request.form.get(i))
```

Here is my html, as you can see the text names match what I have in schema but for some reason request.form.get(i) always returns None in my python code.

```
<form action="/manpower" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="query">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="addNew">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="update">
        </div>          
        <div class="form-group">
            <select name="user">                    
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="bo">bo</option>
                <option value="dog2">dog2</option>
                <option value="dunkin">dunkin</option>
                <option value="tom">tom</option>                    
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class ="form-group">                    
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="username: bo" type="text"/>
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="phone: None" type="text"/>
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="postal_code" placeholder="postal_code: None" type="text"/>
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="address: None" type="text"/>
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="email: None" type="text"/>                    
        </div>           
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Please post your full routing function. Do you check whether it is a 'POST' or 'GET' request?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and it's pretty simple. request.form sends everything that was posted from flask and from that I can figure out how to iterate my loops. Thanks for the help guys.

```
request.form
```